# How to semplify code for query in cakePHP 1.2

Tags: php, cakephp, optimization, cakephp-1.2

I have this portion of code in my controller:

```
if ((!empty($params))&&(isset($params['autore'])||isset($params['titolo'])||isset($params['editore'])||isset($params['anno']))) {
        $a = $params['autore'];
    if (strpos($a,' ')||strpos($a,',')) {
        $autore_diviso = explode(" ", $a);
        $this->set('autore_diviso', $autore_diviso);
    }
    $t = $params['titolo'];
    $e = $params['editore'];
    $an = $params['anno'];
    $an2 = $params['anno2'];

    if ($an==''&&$an2=='')
            $conditions = array('AND' => array('autori LIKE' => "%$a%",
                'editore LIKE' => "%$e%",'titolo LIKE' => "%$t%"));                     
        else    
        {
            if ($an=='')
                      $conditions = array(array('AND' => array('autori LIKE' => "%$a%",
                      'editore LIKE' => "%$e%",'titolo LIKE' => "%$t%")),
                    'AND' => array('anno <=' => "$an2"));
            if ($an2=='')
                $conditions = array(array('AND' => array('autori LIKE' => "%$a%", 'editore LIKE' => "%$e%",'titolo LIKE' => "%$t%")),                   'AND' => array('anno >=' => "$an"));
            else
                $conditions = array('AND' => array(
                            'autori LIKE' => "%$a%", 'editore LIKE' => "%$e%",
                            'titolo LIKE' => "%$t%"),
                            'OR' => array('anno BETWEEN ? AND ?' => array($an,$an2)));
        }
        $u = $this->paginate('CdBiblio',$conditions);
            $this->set('query', $u);
    }
```

(Where 'anno' means 'year' - titolo = 'title' and editore = 'publisher').

How can I simplify this code? 
 
Also, I need to introduce the possibility for the user to search 2 authors (so I would add more if ... else statements).

Comment: have you considered [CakeDC Search](https://github.com/CakeDC/search)? It's really quite good

Comment: formatting your code for readability would be a good start

Answer (score -2):

It seems you have the same subquery in all the conditions.

You can use concatenation in this way to save code:

```
//common subquery
$conditions = array('AND' => array(
                        'autori LIKE' => "%$a%", 'editore LIKE' => "%$e%",
                        'titolo LIKE' => "%$t%"));

//for example...  
if(...){
    $conditions+=array('AND' => array('anno <=' => "$an2"));
}else{
    $conditions+=array('OR' => array('anno BETWEEN ? AND ?' => array($an,$an2)));
}

$u = $this->paginate('CdBiblio',$conditions);
```

You can also change the comparisons:

```
if ($an==''&&$an2=='')
```

for

```
if (!$an && !$an2)
```

Oh and... i would use real words for variables. It is always better to understand what is what rather than creating variables with no sense, such as `$a`. This makes things easier for future modifications of the code as well as preventing coding mistakes.

Comment: I tryed, but it says: SQL Error: 1054: Unknown column 'ArrayArrayArray' in 'where clause'

Comment: And there I thought you have some whoodoo skills to make arrays do stuff they shouldn't be able to :)

Comment: Like what? I haven't tried it with arrays inside arrays, but I believe it should also work.

Comment: I've done things a bit more simple but with the same structure: `$conditions = array('Post.status_id' => $statusIds);`  and then `$conditions = $conditions + array('Post.department_id' => $departmentIds);`

Comment: Sorry, but this will just not work: the array keys are the same so the second `'AND'` will overwrite the first. You must use `$conditions[] = array( ... )`. (CakePHP can read nested arrays.)